# How can I access Database Adapter in ZF2 Field Set?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-db

I have followed an example and would like to pass the Database adapter to a fieldset to create a drop down menu.

The code below is how i call the fieldset.
How can i access the database adapter in the BrandFieldset class?

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Application\Form\BrandFieldset',
    'name' => 'brand',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Brand of the product',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of these docs I was able to find a solution.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html

```
'form_elements' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'fieldset' => BrandFieldsetFactory::class
    )
)
```

I needed to call the form using the service locator in the controller like below.

```
$sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
$form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get('Application\Form\CreateForm');
```

In addition I changed the __construct to init.

Answer (score 3):

Instantiating a fieldset is responsibility of the [FormElementManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/FormElementManager/FormElementManagerV3Polyfill.php). When you try to access a form, form element or fieldset, the `FormElementManager` knows where to find and how to create it. This behaviour summerized in [Default Services](https://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.services.html) section of the framework.

Since the proper way of accessing form elements is retrieving them from FormElementManager, I would write a `BrandFieldsetFactory` to inject that DB adapter or further dependencies to fieldset on construction to achieve this.

A ZF3 friendly fieldset factory would look like:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form\Factory;

use Application\Form\BrandFieldset;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class BrandFieldsetFactory
{
    /**
     * @return BrandFieldset
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $fem, $name, array $options = null)
    {
        // FormElementManager is child of AbstractPluginManager 
        // which makes it a ContainerInterface instance
        $adapter = $fem->getServiceLocator()->get('Your\Db\Adapter');
        return new BrandFieldset($adapter);
    }
}
```

At this point, `BrandFieldset` should extend the `Zend\Form\Fieldset\Fieldset` and it's constructor may look like following:

```
private $dbAdapter;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function __construct(My/Db/Adapter $db, $options = [])
{
    $this->dbAdapter = $db;
    return parent::__construct('brand-fieldset', $options);
}
```

Finally, in `module.config.php` file I'd have a configuration to tell `FormElementManager` about this factory:

```
<?php

use Application\Form\BrandFieldset;
use Application\Form\Factory\BrandFieldsetFactory;

return [
    // other config

    // Configuration for form element manager
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            BrandFieldset::class => BrandFieldsetFactory::class
        ],
    ],
];
```

> **HINT:** The `BrandFieldset::init()` method will be called automatically by FormElementManager after construction. You can put any post-initialization logic into this method.

Comment: Can this be used in ZF2?  I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Sure, after make the factory ZF2 friendly, it should work. Just add a createService() method into the factory just like other zf2 factories and call _invoke from that method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If I var dump the $db in the fieldset I get the name of the class ("brandfieldset").  It doesn't look like the factory is ever called (if I exit or var dump in the factory nothing happends)

Comment: The Factory never seems to get called.      public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $fem, $name, array $options = null)
    {
  echo 'does this work';
  exit;
        // FormElementManager is child of AbstractPluginManager 
        // which makes it a ContainerInterface instance
        $adapter = $fem->getServiceLocator()->get('Your\Db\Adapter');
        return new BrandFieldset($adapter);
    }